# Edit Order return Guest form

Tags: magento2, template, sales-order, forms, returns

I like to edit order return guest form. I edited in

> `app/design/frontend/[theme]/Magento_Sales/templates/guest/form.phtml`

**but form settings are in**

**vendor/magento/module-sales/Helper/Guest.php.**
 How to edit **Guest.php** file?

Comment: Did you try to override the block file?

Comment: Yeah i tried, then goes to full blank page.